# Dialogs with bot within group chat in MS Teams

Tags: botframework

My question is about handling conversations with a bot in a group chat in Microsoft Teams. I'm experimenting with basic example from the MS tutorial:

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var restify = require('restify');

//=========================================================
// Bot Setup
//=========================================================

// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
   console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});

// Create chat bot
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

//=========================================================
// Bots Dialogs
//=========================================================

var intents = new builder.IntentDialog();
bot.dialog('/', intents);

intents.matches(/^change name/i, [
    function (session) {
        session.beginDialog('/profile');
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.send('Ok... Changed your name to %s', session.userData.name);
    }
]);

intents.onDefault([
    function (session, args, next) {
        if (!session.userData.name) {
            session.beginDialog('/profile');
        } else {
            next();
        }
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.send('Hello %s!', session.userData.name);
    }
]);

bot.dialog('/profile', [
    function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Hi! What is your name?');
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.userData.name = results.response;
        session.endDialog();
    }
]);
```

This simple dialog works great in the one-to-one chat: https://screencast.com/t/VgjlxYMea
But in a group chat there is something wrong with recognizing intents: https://screencast.com/t/f7JAr7HFAY7

My first thought was that with a bot mention I should update pattern of the intent, from `/^change name/i` to `/.*change name/i` , apparently bot started to recognize the intent: https://screencast.com/t/i66rDQj0pC ... but still no luck with entering dialog.

Comment: Hi Anton, could you send an updated screenshot of your chatbot after you changed you regex? Your last image isn't 100% clear as a replication of the initial issue. After you set your name as Anton at 1:38pm, you don't say "change name" before you utter "Sam" again. 

After this exchange, you do trigger the /profile dialog, and say Sam, but you don't include the response from the bot afterwards.

Comment: Hey Steven, thanks for the interest in my question. Apparently fix was obvious - event in Reply dialog I have to mention bot in every message.